# android how to check if a Point is inside my screen

Tags: android, google-maps, map-projections

i'm getting a Point object throw my MapView Projectiion object.

I have a list of Overlays and i want to check if each Overlay is inside my current screen (which is of curse depends on the zoom level).

I couldn't find a way to check if a given point is inside the screen.

What i did  found out is that when i'm Logging the Points from the Projection, the points that're not in the screen have negative value..

is it true to say that if a Point has a negative value it is outside my screen ?

Answer (score 6):

```
    GeoPoint yourPoint = null;// w/e point u wanna see is on the screen

    Point newPoint = null; // x/y point

    mapView.getProjection().toPixels(yourPoint, newPoint); //convert to xy Point

    int height = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;

    int width = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;

    Rect screen = new Rect(0,0,width,height); //rect that represents your Screen

    if(screen.contains(newPoint.x, newPoint.y){
         // your point is on the screen
    }
```

Comment: I don't know you made a mistake, or there was something changed, but height and width are wrong in Rect constructor (0,0,width,height).